# Integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

What the value of $$\int\limits_{|x|\geq1}\frac{1}{|x|^n}dx , \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n?$$ This integral is part of other problem.

Comment: Have you try n-dimension sphere substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral
$$
K(n,\alpha) := \int\limits_{|x|\geq1}\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}dx , \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n?
$$
converges only if $\alpha > n$.  But as far as I know there is no known closed form.  Perhaps there are asymptotics as $\alpha \downarrow n$.

Comment: No known closed form? It's $\int_1^\infty r^{n-1-\alpha}\,dr$ times the volume of unit sphere.

Answer (score 0):

That integral diverges for all $n$ because the surface of a shell at radius $|x|=r$ is proportional to $r^{n-1|}$ so the integral after integrating out the variables in hyperspherical coordinates other than $r$ is some constant (involving $\pi^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ times $r^{-1}$, which of course diverges logarithmically.